# Get a local path using PHP

Tags: php, path, directory

Can I get a path like this using PHP ?

`c:\\wamp\\www\\mysite\\blabla\n`

from the script running in "mysite" or mysite/blabla

basically I want to find the full file path, not just the one from the server, which in this case is located in www :)

Comment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` or `__FILE__` or `$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really simple!

```
print $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use `dirname(__FILE__)`. You can also use just `__DIR__` as of PHP 5.3

Answer (score 3):

do a print_r on $_SERVER and check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). Works for PHP >= 4.0.2